# combine 2 observables

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

I am using firestore as database and use angularfire2 to retrieve data from it.
I have a collection of comments, in which each comment stores a user id. I want to get the user info such as user displayName and photoURL, and then combine it with the original comments stream to result in a stream consists of both comment info and user info. My attempt to combine the comments and users stream as follows:

```
const comments$ = this.afs.collection(`comments`).valueChanges();
const users$ = this.afs.collection(`comments`).valueChanges().pipe(
  switchMap((comments) => {
    return comments.map(comment => this.afs.doc(`users/${comment.uid}`).valueChanges());
  })
);
const combine = zip(comments$, users$, (comments, users) => {
  return {...comments, ...users };
});
```

The above code failed to achieve what I want. Essentially it reads the user id from each of the comment, and then use this user id to find the related user info, and combines them together as a resulting stream. The comments$ observable works properly. The users$ observable didn't work. Also, I am not sure if zip is a proper use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have missed the collection name for *users*. Second line.

```
const comments$ = this.afs.collection(`comments`).valueChanges();
const users$ = this.afs.collection(/** HERE?? **/).valueChanges().pipe(
  switchMap((comments) => {
    return comments.map(comment => this.afs.doc(`users/${comment.uid}`).valueChanges());
  })
);
const combine = zip(comments$, users$, (comments, users) => {
  return {...comments, ...users };
});
```

Also it doesn't seem to work, because in **must** return an observable inside of `switchMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching more for a **combineLatest** instead of a zip. Since every time one stream emits you need to recalculate your output stream.

The merge function seems not good too, If I have understood well, you have to join every comment with its user, for that, you can simply do:

```
comments.map((comment) => {
      return {
          ...comment,
          user: users.find(user => user.id === comment.user_id)}
   })
```

Here is a simple code snippet where both streams are joined this way, having as a final result an **array of comments with its user information**:

```js
function mockUsers$() {
  return rxjs.of([
  {id: '1', name: 'user1'},
  {id: '2', name: 'user2'},
  {id: '3', name: 'user3'}
]);
}

function mockComments$() {
  return rxjs.of([
  {id: '1', user_id: '1', comment: 'user1 comment 1'},
  {id: '2', user_id: '1', comment: 'user1 comment 2'},
  {id: '3', user_id: '1', comment: 'user1 comment 3'},
  {id: '4', user_id: '2', comment: 'user2 comment'},
  {id: '5', user_id: '3', comment: 'user3 comment 1'},
  {id: '6', user_id: '3', comment: 'user3 comment 2'}]);
}

const comments$ = mockComments$();
const users$ = mockUsers$()

rxjs.combineLatest(users$, comments$, (users, comments) => comments.map((comment) => {
      return {
          ...comment,
          user: {...users.find(user => user.id === comment.user_id)}}
   })   
).subscribe((data) => console.log('Comments with user info: ', data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!